# javascript array to multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a question that follows this thread. Its a follow up to this answer.

[Google Apps Script Spreadsheets - Write Array to cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495588/google-apps-script-spreadsheets-write-array-to-cells)

how do i get

```
var employees=["Adam","Barb","Chris"];
```

to look like this?

```
var employees=[["Adam"],["Barb"],["Chris"]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var employees=["Adam","Barb","Chris"];

var newEmployees = employees.map( function( item ){ return [ item ]; } );
```

Comment: @HMR But a suitable shim is given on MDN as well. So just add the shim and you should be alright.

Comment: Yes, here is the map for browsers that don't implement it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility Just needed mentioning if you need support for IE<9

Comment: @HMR Did you notice, that this link is already part of my answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
var employees = ["Adam", "Barb", "Chris"];

for (var i = employees.length; i--;) {
    employees[i] = [employees[i]];
}
```